# Apache Shiro Programmatic Configuration

Tags: java, apache, ini, shiro

I would like to configure my application (that already works fine with Shiro) using Shiro programmatic configuration and leaving shiro.ini file.

I use the official tutorial [here](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-ProgrammaticConfiguration).

This is the code i implemented:

```
    Realm realm = new AuthAuthRealmFactory();
    org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager(realm);

    //Make the SecurityManager instance available to the entire application via static memory: 
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

The problem is when i remove shiro.ini file i experience this exception:

```
> org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment               - Checking
> any specified config locations.                                       
> -   org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment               - No INI instance or config locations specified.  Trying default config
> locations.                     -   org.apache.shiro.io.ResourceUtils  
> - Opening resource from class path [shiro.ini]                                                         -   org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils                         - Resource [shiro.ini] was not found via the thread context ClassLoader.
> Trying the current ClassLoader... -   org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils
> - Resource [shiro.ini] was not found via the current class loader.  Trying the system/application ClassLoader... -  
> org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils                         - Resource
> [shiro.ini] was not found via the thread context, current, or
> system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted. 
> Returning null. -   org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment        
> - Unable to load optional path 'classpath:shiro.ini'.
> - java.io.IOException: Resource [classpath:shiro.ini] could not be found.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Shiro's servlet plugin (fragment):
https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/support/servlet-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml

You would need to configure Shiro directly (either your web.xml or equivalent) and make sure the default impl is not loaded.  If you share a little more about your app (what type is it, how are you trying to configure Shiro, I'm guessing we can help you more directly)

Comment: Thanks Brian and sorry for late reply. You're right i've missed to not load the default impl!